# C - Loading data from a file in an array

Tags: c, arrays, list, file, csv

Okay so I am working in C and stackoverflow has been helping me a lot so far, however I am still stuck! Im not sure why this wont work! I am trying to store a tokenized file in an array, however it doesn't seem to be working here is what I am trying:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int lines=0, i=0, a=0;
    char strings[50], *err=" ";

    FILE *file;
char *array[100][4];
    file=fopen("inventory.csv", "a+");
    if(file==NULL){
        return 1;}
    err=malloc(100);

        while(a<100 && fgets(strings, sizeof strings, file)!=NULL){



        int i;
        char *p;

        i = 0;
        p = strtok (strings,",");
        while (i<4 && p != NULL)
        {
            array[a][i++] = strdup(p);
            p = strtok (NULL, ",");
        }
            a++;
        }
   lines=a; 

    if(argv[1]!=NULL){
        if(strcmp(argv[1], "list")==0){
            printf("\nName, Quantity, Reorder limit, Cost\n\n");
            for(a=0;a<lines;a++){
                for(i=0;i<4;i++){
                    printf("%s ", array[a][i]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

    else if(strcmp(argv[1], "reorder")==0){
        int i=0;
        printf("We need to purchase more of the following items: \n");
        for(i=0;i<lines;i++){
            if(strtod(array[i][1], &err)<=strtod(array[i][2],&err)){

                printf("%s\n", array[i][0]);


            }
        }
    }
    else if(strcmp(argv[1], "deduct")==0){
        if(argv[2]){
            int i=0;
            char str[100];

            for(i=0;i<lines;i++){
                if(strcmp(argv[2], array[i][0])==0){
                    if(strtod(array[i][1],&err)-1>0){
                        sprintf(str,"%f",strtod(array[i][1],&err)-1);
                        array[i][1]=str;
                        printf("Success\n");
                        fseek(file, 0, 1);
                        sprintf(str,"%s,%s,%s,%s", array[i][0], array[i][1], array[i][2], array[i][3]);
                        fwrite(str,1,sizeof(str+1),file);
                    }
                    else{
                        printf("There are none left!\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            printf("Enter a food item");
        }
    }
    else if(strcmp(argv[1], "add")==0){
        fseek(file, 0, 2);
        char str[100];
        sprintf(str,"%s,%s,%s,%s\n",argv[2],argv[3],argv[4],argv[5]);
        fwrite(str,1,sizeof(str),file);

    }
    else{
        printf("Please enter an argument: list, reorder, deduct _name_, add _name_ _qty_ _reorderlimit_ _price_\n");
    }
}
int j;

for(i=0;i<lines;i++){
    for(j=0; j<3; j++){
        free(array[i][j]);
}
}

fclose(file);
return 0;
}
```

I have fixed the list and add functions, however, I still receive core dump after every run, and deduct doesn't work, (says success, core dumps, but doesn't update the file) and individulaAverage still doesn't find the input (name) to be == to experiment(i);

This is the csv file:

```
hotdog,10,2,1.5
bun,10,2,0.5
burger,100,10,2.0
cheese,100,10,2.25
pickle,10,2,1.0
ham,2,2,1.0
salmon,5,1,5.0
steak,5,1,7.0
pork,10,2,6.0
fries,1000,100,3.0
```

Comment: Minor usage point: "store" usually means moving data from memory to a file. Most of us would have said you want to _load_ data from a file into an array.

Comment: You keep reusing the space in `strings` to store different data (each line in turn), but you save pointers to different locations in `strings` in the `array`.  This leads to the overwriting you're seeing.  Allocate storage (`strdup()`?) for each string as you read it.  Then remember to free the allocated space.

Comment: Could you explain what strdup() does and how to use it in this context? @JonathanLeffler

Comment: Implementation: `char *strdup(const char *str) { size_t len = strlen(str) + 1; char *dup = malloc(len); if (dup != 0) memmove(dup, str, len); return dup; }`  The function `strdup()` duplicates a string by allocating enough memory for a copy of the string (remembering that there's a zero byte at the end of the string) and copies the original string to the new string if the allocation was successful.  It returns the duplicate pointer (null or a valid value) regardless.  You'd replace `array[a][i++] = p;` with `array[a][i++] = strdup(p);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep reusing the space in `strings` to store different data (each line in turn), but you save pointers to different locations in `strings` in the `array`. This leads to the overwriting you're seeing. Allocate storage ([`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html)
? — part of POSIX but not in Standard C) for each string as you read it. Then remember to free the allocated space.

> Could you explain what strdup() does and how to use it in this context?

#### Implementation

```
char *strdup(const char *str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str) + 1;
    char *dup = malloc(len);
    if (dup != 0)
        memmove(dup, str, len);
    return dup;
}
```

#### Commentary

The function `strdup()` duplicates a string by allocating enough memory for a copy of the string (remembering that there's a zero byte at the end of the string) and copies the original string to the new string if the allocation was successful. It returns the duplicate pointer (null or a valid value) regardless.

You'd replace `array[a][i++] = p;` with `array[a][i++] = strdup(p);`

You'd also need a loop similar to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        free(a[i][j]);
}
```

(Of course, if you exit immediately, the loop becomes optional, but it is a very good idea to ensure that you know where and when there is a `free()` for each explicit or implicit `malloc()` that you execute.)